# Returning multiple files in a stream in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, stream

I have a initiative where I need to take in documents and convert them into images in a WCF application. When a file such as word document is passed through the stream, I will get multiple images for the document, i.e one image for each page in the document.

When I want to return these multiple images back to the client. Whats a good way to return all these files through the stream? I also need to tell the client what the names of the files would be and how many files I am returning, whats a good way to do that?

This is my first time working with WCF/web services.

I also need to consider how long a conversion is taking, if its taking too long or creating too many images I need to get back with an error. Is using SOAP faults a good way to tell the client?

Do I just make an array of byes and return the array to the client? or Do I combine all the images into one stream and return it? If the size of the stream is too big (i.e more than 2 MB) wouldn't it have problems(slow) transferring the files?

Comment: If you're concerned with the amount of data you're transferring using WCF, check out this interesting article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

Comment: Also, whats a good way to make this service generic? Can Java and other language clients call this Web method and receive the same file stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can transfer streams of any size and you shoudl probably just write the stream directly. To combine multiple files in a stream I think the easiest thing would be to create a zip file containing all content and sent that.

Your method signature should simply return a Stream which WCF will sent directly to the underlying binding. There are some limitations on which bindings you can use, but WebHttpBinding for one supports it.

Comment: How would the client separate the files from that one stream? Is it possible to do it without zipping? I also need to let the client know the transaction ID and the names of the files.

Comment: Then you should probably write some kind of control structure your self. You could create a header including number of files in the stream and names and sizes of each stream. To avoid a purely binary format you could also choose to return XML (still inside the stream) and let the file content be base64-encoded. For large files that would be a bore though and you might choose to split into two methods where one returned control data and the other the content of each individual file.

Comment: What do you mean by split into two methods? So the client would need to call two methods? One for getting the stream and one for getting the XML information? But How does a client separate out all the images from the stream?

Comment: I Think combining the streams Will inevitably cause a hard to interpret binary format or some hard to construct XML. So rather I would create one method that returned a set of file identifiers in json or XML and another method where the content of one file was returned given its identifier. It would then be the clients responsibility to get the identifiers from method A and one call to method B for each file. It would cause some overhead to make multiple requests but that would probably be acceptable to avoid homegrown complicated file fornats.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, so I am designing it so that I will return an XML file in one method with the number of files in the stream and the size of each file. Another method would be called to get the stream from the service. Is that what you were saying? 

Thank you for your responses! So you know how this would work if my application is in WCF and the clients are in EJB/Java.

Comment: Either that or even simpler Letting each file be returned in one method invokation. This deviates somewhat from your question but I think the simplification is a big advantage.

Comment: But the thing is, if a client connects to the service, its not going to create an object of my service. So, if a client calls for one file, and makes another call for another image file, how would the web service know they are interrelated calls? I will have this service on 6 servers with a message queue system. I am not sure how I would be relating two different calls if they are not using the same object. Its a separate call each time right? Client just sends in one document, which creates multiple images, images have to be stored in one place.